# modular nginx configuration not working

Tags: laravel, nginx, hhvm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 + nginx + HHVM on a Unix socket.
I have a few projects, all running under the same IP in different subdirectories.  I have been trying to make the configuration modular, so as projects get changed, only small changes are needed. However, not a single site is working. What I get is a plain '404 File Not Found' page without HTML markup. Nothing showed up from both nginx and HHVM's error log.

Here's my directory structure:

```
nginx/
  main/
    index.php
  phpmyadmin/
    index.php
  laravel/
    public/
      index.php
```

And my nginx configuration:

global

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name localhost;

  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log     /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
  charset utf-8;

  root /usr/share/nginx;

  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/main.conf;
  #include /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf;
  #include /etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel.conf;

  include hhvm.conf;

  # Deny .htaccess file access
  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }
}
```

main.conf

```
location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/main;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =400;
}
```

hhvm.conf

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    # fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: `404 File Not Found` is a HHVM error message.
I think you messed up with the paths.
Instead of `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` you could try `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/main$fastcgi_script_name;` to test it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. No errors pop up either. By the way, hardcoding that path into the config seems not very good.

Comment: Of course its not good, it was just to check if $document_root is false

Comment: Stupid me. Your line does work (I got a typo :( ). So what should I change to make it compatible across projects?

Comment: As I turned on the debug level error log, I found out $document_root is at /usr/share/nginx. How is this variable decided? Googling it only gives examples (instead of docs), and I believe the root is overwritten in the main.conf.

Comment: I believe the reason is the `include hhvm.conf` line is out of scope (out of the location block), as a result the root from the global file is used. The current workaround is to put that line into all of my project configs. It works, but I hope there will be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to create a vhost for every project. So you have one domain (without a folder in the url) and it's modular too.

But if you want to stay with your structure, it's maybe possible with this config:

```
# For example for your main:
location /main {
  root /usr/share/nginx/main;
  include hhvm.conf;
  index index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =400;
}
```

These blocks are needed for /main, /phpmyadmin and /laravel.

BUT, the problem with this solution could be that laravel for example is easiest to use on a domain like `laravel.local` and not within a folder like `pc.local/laravel` because of the url rewriting you need for it.
That would be another reason to switch to vhosts with an own domain for each of your folders. Subdomains are possible too.

Comment: I knew getting a domain makes things easier, except that I don't want a domain (yet). I don't want to mess with the hosts file either. You are right, Laravel will be a pain to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my updated config files so it works (Laravel is still work in progress with only homepage working, it is a pain):

PKeidel's answer is accepted since he inspired me in making this. Thanks!

main

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name localhost;

  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log     /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
  charset utf-8;

  include sites-available/main.conf; 
  include sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf;
  include sites-available/laravel.conf;

  # Deny .htaccess file access
  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }
}
```

main.conf

```
location ^~ / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/yoyo;
  include php-template;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

phpmyadmin.conf

```
location ^~ /pma {
  root /usr/share/nginx;
  include php-template;
  try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
}
```

php-template

```
index index.php;
include hhvm.conf;
```